# Zope/Plone 2.9 strange session behaviour?

Tags: session, caching, plone, zope

This is what my server is running: (Zope 2.9.6-final, python 2.4.4, linux2)

I have a log-in form where user have to authenticate to the system.
The Session expires after some time (say, 20 minutes).

If I am on a page (call it x) and my session expires (mean that when I click on a link, I will redirect to log in form) or I restart the server manually something strange happens: If I log-in again and click on some links (say all but not x) the page will be sended to me. If I request the x page (where I was before the session expire) the server redirect me on the log-in page (like I have no permission to access that page).

If I disable the cache on my browser, that problem seems to disappear.

Anyone knows what happening?

Comment: No, can you describe the configuration you have done to your (presumably) Plone 2.5 site? Or, is this a default site? What result do you expect?

Comment: I've tried to remove every object that I previously had in RAM cache and HTTP cache (on plone server) and it seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen problems where the 401 redirect ends up being cached by proxy caches. Plone 4.1 now sets appropriate cache headers to avoid this.